# Why does a stronger heart cause blood pressure go down

Tags: human-biology, cardiology, blood-circulation, blood-pressure

Intuitively, why does a stronger heart cause blood pressure to go down? The answers I've found from a cursory google search seem to indicate that it has to "work less hard" to pump the blood and that it "beats more slowly," but I do not immediately understand the implications of this.

Furthermore, if it is due to a slower heart beat in a stronger heart that blood pressure is lower, then how does (/is it true that) blood pressure remains lower in those with a stronger heart during exercise? **Wouldn't a stronger heart beating just as fast as a weaker heart lead to higher blood pressure?**

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I think this might be a better fit for [medicalsciences.se]. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: My intuition may be wrong, but see [Bernoulli’s equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_principle) for an incompressible fluid. Modeling the circulatory system as a closed loop, the pressure exerted on arterial walls by blood decreases with increasing blood velocity. Assuming a stronger heart pumps blood faster, a stronger heart should reduce blood pressure compared to a weaker heart and slower blood flow.

Comment: Use of the word “stronger” is not clear. The flow rate needs to be considered and those who are very fit have a lower resting heart rate, a higher maximum and tend to need a lower beats per minute when doing the same exercise level as an unfit person.

Comment: A heart that _is_ stronger (bigger; thicker walls) does not need to _work_ stronger. In usual circumstances, the strength of a healthy heart has nothing to do with blood pressure.